# Ограничить права доступа пользователю

Tags: права, linux

Задача - нужно создать нового пользователя в системе. Пользователю нужно ограничить права на изменение всех папок кроме media/. Ну и тех, которые ему нужны для функционирования системы. С такой задачей на линуксе сталкиваюсь впервые. Как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: идея странная, selinux или grsec может помочь чисто теоретически. (если раасмтривать именно в такой постановке) а обычно - делаем группу эту группу указываем в     chown root:newgroup media/;    chmod g+w media/; но это естественно не гарантирует доступ до других директорий, в стандартном acl нет запрещающих атрибутов.---ещё вариант - chroot с mount bind.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте рассуждать логически:
1) `нужные для функционирования системы папки` - как я подозреваю, имеется ввиду home-папка пользователя, где хранятся все его настройки. Изменение системных папок, типа /etc любому пользователю запрещено по-определению;
2) определить для папки /media доступ необходимого пользователя через группу...
3) SElinux - сильная вещь, очень поможет, НО как дополнительное средство к основным правам...

Answer (score 1):

Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью SELinux на ОС основанных на RedHat системах. Подронее можно прочитать например в этой статье: "[Настройка и использование SELinux (selinux limit security linux mac acl)](http://www.opennet.ru/base/sec/selinux_setup.txt.html)"

Есть еще AppArmor и Grsecurity.

Сравшение выше перечисленных систем описан в статье: [Linux Kernel Security (SELinux vs AppArmor vs Grsecurity)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/selinux-vs-apparmor-vs-grsecurity.html)